# How can I transform my PC menu in a hamburger menu for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, hamburger-menu, side-menu

I already have a side menù, I want him to change into a hamburger menù whenever the website is open by a mobile device. I also use bootstrap libraries, I dunno if it can help, it would be better using them. Here's an example of what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>

        div {
            border: solid black 1px;
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            max-width: none !important;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .menu {
            text-align: center;
        }

        button {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="menu">
                    <button>Content 1</button><br>
                    <button>Content 2</button><br>
                    <button>Content 3</button><br>
                    <button>Content 4</button><br>
                    <button>Content 5</button><br>
                    <button>Content 6</button><br>
                    <button>Content 7</button><br>
                    <button>Content 8</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, it's easier to do it with Bootstrap like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="yourlogo.com"  class="d-inline-block align-top" width="32" height="32" alt="Your logo" />web.com</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-bar-content" aria-controls="navigation-bar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-bar-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When used on a phone, the navigation menu folds into a hamburger. You can verify this, for example, using the developer tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I in Chrome).

Of course, you need to have some sort of search function for that search field or it won't work for you. You can also add a dropdown there, but you must also have JavaScript linked.